# Make double entry table with grid

Tags: r, grid

I want the format of the second table to have a grid, i.e. to have the format of the first table. I attach an image. [image]

The code of the first table is:

```
datos1 = c(12 , 8 , 4 , 6, 4 , 2, 3, 2, 1)
datos11 = c(12 , 8 , 4 ,  3, 2, 1, 6, 4 , 2)
datos2 = c(3 , 6 , 12 , 2, 4 , 8, 1, 2, 4)
datos12 = c(3 , 6 , 12 , 1, 2, 4,2, 4 , 8)
datos3 = c(2 , 1 , 4 , 4, 2 , 8, 6, 3, 12)
datos13 = c(2 , 1 , 4 , 6, 3, 12, 4, 2 , 8)
datos4 = c(4 , 2 , 1 , 8, 4 , 2, 12, 6, 3)
datos14 = c(4 , 2 , 1 , 12, 6, 3, 8, 4 , 2)
datos5 = c(1 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)
datos15 = c(1 , 2 , 4 , 3, 6, 12, 2, 4 , 8)
datos6 = c(4 , 8 , 12 , 2, 4 , 6, 1, 2, 3)
datos16 = c(4 , 8 , 12 , 1, 2, 3, 2, 4 , 6)
datos7 = c(1 , 2 , 3 , 2, 4 , 6, 4, 8, 12)
datos17 = c(3 , 2 , 1 , 6, 4 , 2, 12, 8, 4)
datos8 = c(1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 8 , 12, 2, 4, 6)
datos18 = c(2 , 1 , 3 , 4, 2 , 6, 8, 4, 12)
datos9 = c(2 , 4 , 6 , 4, 8 , 12, 1, 2, 3)
datos19 = c(6 , 4 , 2 , 12, 8 , 4, 3, 2, 1)
datos10 = c(2 , 4 , 6 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 , 12)
datos20 = c(6 , 2 , 4 , 12, 4, 8, 3, 1 , 2)

w9 <- sample(list(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5,datos6,datos7,datos8,datos9,datos10,datos11,datos12,datos13,datos14,datos15,datos16,datos17,datos18,datos19,datos20), 1) 
w9 <- unlist(w9)
tabla = cbind (expand.grid (list (Y = c ("[2,4)","[4,6)","[6,8]") ,
X = c ("6","8","9.5" ))), count = w9)
p1<- ftable (xtabs(count ~ Y + X, tabla ))

grid.table(tabla, rows = NULL)
```

And the code of the second table is:

```
p1
```

Adding

```
colnames(p1) = c("6","8","9.5")
rownames(p1) = c("[2,4)","[4,6)","[6,8]")
```

And

```
myt <- ttheme_default(
        colhead = list(fg_params=list(col="black"),
                     bg_params=list(fill="grey")),
         rowhead = list(fg_params=list(col="black", fontface="bold",hjust=0.5, x=0.5),
                       bg_params=list(fill="grey")))




grid::grid.newpage()
grid.table(p1[1:3,1:3], theme=myt)

rs = tableGrob(cbind("Y\\X"=rownames(p1)[1:3]), 
               rows=NULL, 
               theme=ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params=list(fill="grey"), 
                                              fg_params=list(fontface="bold"))))

grid::grid.draw(gtable_combine(rs, tableGrob(p1[1:3, 1:3], rows=NULL)))
```

I get the table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **xtable** package:

```r
latex <- print(xtableFtable(p1), floating = FALSE, print.results = FALSE)

writeLines(
  c(
    "\\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}",
    "\\usepackage{caption}",
    "\\begin{document}",
    "\\minipage{\\textwidth}",
    latex,
    "\\captionof{table}{My caption}",
    "\\endminipage",
    "\\end{document}"
  ),
  "myTable.tex"
)
```

You will have to add some dollars to compile **myTable.tex** to PDF.

I have not checked, but I think you can grey out some lines.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I finally got the table I wanted, as I indicated above.